# InDesign: missing links reported, will a PDF export work for printing?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, print-production

After exporting from InDesign to PDF everything looks in place, while InDesign shows a lot of links missing. I am wondering if it could be printed without problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the links were broken upon export, what was *actually* exported were the low resolution **preview** images.

In most cases **no. They generally can NOT be "printed without problems".**.

You can preflight the PDF to check the objects and see that their resolution is probably pretty low and unacceptable.